# What stops a TCP endhost from being a bad player?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm talking about [congestion control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Congestion_control) specifically.  In TCP, when a host detects a congestion via dropped packets or whatnot, it's supposed to decrease its flow so as to improve the network condition as a whole.

However, couldn't a bad host keep sending packets at max rate at the cost of others?  If there are a million hosts and only one bad host, then congestion can still be largely avoided (because all other hosts correctly implement the congestion control algorithm), but the one bad host will have an advantage in terms of packet transmission rate.  So the question is, is there anything that prevents a host from behaving selfishly as such?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an inadvertantly or deliberately broken TCP/IP stack could cause  harm and there are actually lots of broken stacks out there. But, in your case there are conflicting interests in the TCP stack: on one side you want to send as fast as possible but on the other side you need to have a reliable delivery. The latter means that you have to buffer all the data until you get an ACK from the peer. If you don't decrease the bandwidth when packets get lost you will probably loose more packets and have to buffer them all inside your hosts until you get the ACK which will more and more increase the memory usage of your host.

Answer (score 0):

A host which does not comply with RFC 1122 &ff 'Requirements for Internet Hosts' cannot be legally connected to the Internet.